# How to calculate the time difference in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

I have a time entry as follows:

FromTime:73400secs in Time format: 20:23
ToTime:73624secs in Time format: 20:27

When taking difference of the secs it is : 224secs  in Time Format : 00:03:44
but when taking difference of the Time Format it is: 00:04

Why is this difference happening?
Which is the correct way to show the difference in the fromTime & toTime?

Comment: code or it didn't happen :)
(*I mean please post the relevant code, otherwise we cannot tell what is going wrong and what you are actually trying to do*)

Comment: If your timeformat is `hours:minutes` how would it be able to calculate the number of seconds? This information is lost when converting 73400secs to 20hours:23min The correct way either is to use the difference in seconds and (if you want) convert the resulting number of seconds to a timespan `hours:minutes:seconds`, or to use a timeformat, which also contains seconds, such that 73624secs is converted to 20:27:04

Comment: also, the 4 in your timeformat is minutes. So that would be 4*60 seconds = 240 seconds. Which seems about right, since you have lost sub-minute precision after changing to a minutes format.

Comment: @derpirscher  yes, the seconds of the time entries are missed why verifying. They are 20:23:20, 20:27:04 resp. Now the difference is the same. Thank you